# Synchronise svg animation

Tags: animation, svg

Tell me, please, how to synchronize svg animation. Growing line and moving circle. I want the circle to always be on top of the line.

```css
body {
  background-image: radial-gradient(circle farthest-corner at center, #1c262b 0, #000 100%)
}

#example {
  height: 90vh;
  display: block;
  margin: 5vh auto;
}

.st0 {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #e2080c;
  stroke-miterlimit: 10;
  stroke-width: 1;
}

#rightCircle {
  animation: animationRightCircle 2s linear;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes animationRightCircle {
  0% {
    transform: translate(320px, 2px)
  }
  33.33% {
    transform: translate(638px, 2px)
  }
  66.66% {
    transform: translate(638px, 638px)
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate(320px, 638px)
  }
}

#rightPath {
  stroke-dasharray: 1276;
  animation: pathGrowing 2s linear;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes pathGrowing {
  0% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 1276;
  }
  100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<svg id="example" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 640 640">
   
   <path id="rightPath" class="st0" d="M320,1 639,1 639,639 320,639"/>
   
   <defs>
  <circle id="myCircle" r="2"  fill="#e2080c"/>
 </defs>

 <use id="rightCircle" xlink:href="#myCircle" />
   
   </svg>
```

I can not understand why the speed of these animations is different. I tried to delay the animation but it did not help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The vertical path segment has double the length of the horizontal segments. Therefore it must be

```
@keyframes animationRightCircle {
  0% {
    transform: translate(320px, 2px)
  }
  25% {
    transform: translate(638px, 2px)
  }
  75% {
    transform: translate(638px, 638px)
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate(320px, 638px)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Example of synchronization of animations for closed loop.

The patch is modified to produce a closed loop.

```
<path  id="rightPath" class="st0" d="M320,1 639,1 639,639 320,639 320,1"/>
```

Changed the percentages of synchronizing the ball animation and drawing the path

```css
body {
  background-image: radial-gradient(circle farthest-corner at center, #1c262b 0, #000 100%)
}

#example {
  height: 90vh;
  display: block;
  margin: 5vh auto;
}

.st0 {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #e2080c;
  stroke-miterlimit: 10;
  stroke-width: 2;
}

#rightCircle {
  animation: animationRightCircle 5s linear;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes animationRightCircle {
0.1% {
    transform: translate(320px, 2px)
  } 
 16.6% {
    transform: translate(640px, 2px)
  }
  49.8% {
    transform: translate(640px, 640px)
  }
  66.4% {
    transform: translate(320px, 640px)
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate(320px, 2px)
  }
}

#rightPath {
  stroke-dasharray: 1914; 
   animation: pathGrowing 5s linear;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes pathGrowing {
  0% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 1914;
  }
  100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<svg id="example" width="50%" height="50%" viewBox="0 0 644 644" >
   
    <path  id="rightPath" class="st0" d="M320,1 639,1 639,639 320,639 320,1"/> 
   
   <defs>
  <circle id="myCircle"   r="3"  fill="#6FE2E2"/>
 </defs>

 <use id="rightCircle"  xlink:href="#myCircle" />  
 
   
   </svg>
```

### SVG solution

Maybe it's better to use the SVG option? There is no need to calculate percentages of animation time.
It is not necessary to calculate the transformation of the movement of the ball along a given path.

The binding of the object to the path is the SVG `mpath` command.

```html
<svg id="example" width="50%" height="50%" viewBox="0 -8 650 650">
   <defs>
  <circle id="myCircle"   r="4"  />
 </defs> 
   <path id="rightPath" fill="none" "stroke-dashoffset="1280" stroke-dasharray="1280" stroke-width="2" stroke="red" d="M320,1 639,1 639,639 320,639">
     <animate attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" from="1280" to="0" dur="5s" fill="freeze" />
   </path>
    
  <use id="rightCircle" xlink:href="#myCircle" fill="teal" > 
 
  <animateMotion id="animMotionZurGen" dur="5s" repeatCount="1" fill="freeze" >
                        <mpath xlink:href="#rightPath"/>
        </animateMotion> 
    </use>    

   </svg>
```

If you need to modify the animation loop, you only need to change the path of the object's motion path.

```
 <path  id="rightPath" class="st0" d="M320,1 639,1 639,639 320,639 320,1"/>
```

```html
<svg id="example" width="50%" height="50%" viewBox="0 -8 650 650">
   <defs>
  <circle id="myCircle"   r="4"  />
 </defs> 
   <path id="rightPath" fill="none" "stroke-dashoffset="1914" stroke-dasharray="1914" stroke-width="2" stroke="red" d="M320,1 639,1 639,639 320,639 320,1">
     <animate attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" from="1914" to="0" dur="5s" fill="freeze" />
   </path>
    
  <use id="rightCircle" xlink:href="#myCircle" fill="teal" > 
 
  <animateMotion id="animMotionZurGen" dur="5s" repeatCount="1" fill="freeze" >
                        <mpath xlink:href="#rightPath"/>
        </animateMotion> 
    </use>    

   </svg>
```

Comment: Thanks, Alexandr for your advice. I am completely satisfied by CSS animation. https://codepen.io/BlackStar1991/pen/ZawJMw